# Gold Badger reopening a duplicated question to answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, tag-badges

I've seen a user with a gold badge doing the same behavior already twice, which is: reopening a straightforward duplicate question, just to answer it  and with that receive some rep.
The first time that happened  I flagged it to the mods but I got this:

> He wasn't the only one to vote to reopen, and I don't see much in the
>   way of abuse here.

Yeah, he wasn't the only one, the other one who voted to open the question wants also to answer (and did it).

- [This is the 1st question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577425/css-tic-tac-toe-inline-block-not-working) which I flagged.
- [This is the 2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685109/why-does-my-grid-have-a-lot-of-whitespace-between-each-line)

I marked both questions as duplicates of the same question [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements), and both questions, the same two users answered it.

So what to do when a user with a gold badge reopened a closed duplicate question just to answer it?

*p.s.* As pointed out by Brad Larson, I answered the 2nd question but I thought at the first it was another issue, not the one I marked as duplicated. You can see my revision in my answer and you will see that. Because I misread the question, my solution doesn't have anything to do with the duplicated question I voted to close.

Comment: I find it interesting that in the second question, you yourself answered it, had your answer downvoted (with a comment by the asker), deleted that answer, and only then voted to close the question. That looks an awful lot like you're retaliating against the asker for downvoting your answer.

Comment: @BradLarson I thought at the first it was another issue. not the one I marked as duplicated. you can see my revision in my answer and you will see that. because I misread the question. My solution doesn't have anything to do with the duplicated question I voted to

Comment: @all please refrain from mass-downvoting answers to the linked questions which are all given in good faith and pointing out additional issues with OPs code.

Comment: @le_m Answers aren't immune from downvotes just because they were given "in good faith".  Answers are voted on based on their quality and usefulness.  A bad or not useful answer given "in good faith" is still a bad answer.

Comment: @BradLarson In addition to the dippas' point, I don't' see how any of this is "retaliating" against the author of the question.  Having their question closed as a duplicate of a canonical question with great answers that solve their exact problem isn't punishing them in any way.  The person that reopened the obvious duplicate only to post a duplicate answer isn't the one that critiqued his (by his own admission, incorrect) answer, it's just someone unrelated doing something inappropriate.

Comment: @Servy I am talking about mass-downvoting *all* answers without regard for their quality. I get it that some feel the need to punish answerers for not realizing they replied to a possible duplicate though.

Comment: @le_m Going around posting duplicate answers to duplicate questions *aren't* quality or useful answers though.  Additionally in this case at least one of the answerers *specifically stated* that they knew of the duplicate, and felt it *was* a duplicate, and yet both reopened and answered anyway, so while the intention isn't relevant, it's also not what you claim it is.

Comment: a duplicate answer is as useful  as a duplicate question. (or maybe even less)

Comment: @Servy thanks for the explanation. This has been a learning experience. The first question I re-opened, I thought it would simply "vote" to re-open the question, and if there were enough people who felt the question was worded or whatever uniquely enough that it wasn't obvious that the question already had a solution that it would be re-opened. Instead it re-opened immediately. I thought I was contributing as a vote that others could chime in on and be a check/balance.

Comment: @MichaelCoker You have what is called a dupe hammer.  You get that by having a gold tag badge.  You can instantly close something as a dupe and reopen something that was closed as a dupe as long as the question has the tag you have gold on and you did not add the tag yourself.

Comment: In the second question, I assumed since the answer was a duplicate, that the  post should be marked as a duplicate, per Dippas's previous question after he marked it as a duplicate, so I just wasn't going to answer at all or close it because I didn't know what to do. But because Dippas answered, I assumed he didn't think it was a duplicate because of the wording or something (or he would have closed it like he did the previous question), and then @Eitan left a comment...

Comment: *"If the answer is the same, but the question is something that could be found as duplicate almost only by experienced users like yourself, should it still be closed as dupe. because that mean that almost every question here is duplicate"* - so I assumed it was fair game to answer, and as I was answering, Dippas deleted his answer to it and then removed the post. So I assumed the wording was unique enough that the question isn't a duplicate and OP asked to re-open the question, so I did.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm also here - I just want to state that this was not posted as a suggestion or request, but as an innocent question

Comment: @AlonEitan I do not understand.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Eitan's statement is strictly false.  Questions that are fundamentally the same, but where it's not immediately obvious *that* they're the same at a glance are *exactly the questions that we want closed as duplicates the most*.  Those are duplicates that are actually valuable to have on the site (obvious duplicates are best off just being deleted), but duplicating the answers is *not* useful; keeping these duplicate *questions* around is useful *so that they can point people to the canonical*, which of course isn't accomplished when you remove the link to said canonical answer.

Comment: Not like this is an excuse, but I'm still fairly new to the site, I think I started contributing at the beginning of the year, so just to say I'm still learning and glad we have this conversation going. I definitely do not mean to ruffle any feathers or break the rules of the site or anything like that. The first question I re-opened was honestly an accident - I thought I was just voting, and I was wrong. This time I assumed the fact that Dippas himself answered and Eitan's point that it wasn't obvious that the end fix has been discussed on stack billions of times.

Comment: @AlonEitan definitely, you didn't say or encourage anything, but I had the same question and assumed Dippas didn't think it was a duplicate upon reading the question, either, or they wouldn't have answered, so the question seemed like fair game.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Your account has been around for 5 years, you've posted 1,200 posts.  You're not a new user at this point.  You have access to every (non-elected moderator) privilege the site has.  Now sure, not everyone knows everything about the site, and that's okay, but you're not *new* anymore.

Comment: @Servy i just mean I had never answered, asked, voted, etc on the site (just read-only) until this year.

Comment: @MichaelCoker He *didn't* think it was a duplicate, which is why he answered.  But his answer was wrong, because he misunderstood the question (perhaps because the question wasn't as clear as it could be).  All that said, you shouldn't be voting to close or reopen questions because *other* people think they are or aren't duplicates, you should be voting based on whether *you* think they're duplicates or not.  Other people have their own votes to cast.  If you're going to cast a vote, it has your name on it, not theirs, so you need to be able to stand by the decisions you make.

Comment: @NathanOliver This [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348548/gold-badger-reopening-a-duplicated-question-to-answer#comment469334_348548) - It was about something I wrote in that question's comment, so I **didn't** want anybody thinking that I was **trying to suggest** that closing the question as duplicate is worng. I was just asking about it

Comment: @Servy *"Questions that are fundamentally the same, but where it's not immediately obvious that they're the same at a glance are exactly the questions that we want closed as duplicates the most."* Thanks, that clears it up. I didn't know and that was my misunderstanding and I apologize.

Comment: @AlonEitan Okay.. I still don't understand how that related to me telling MichaelCoker that he has a dupe hammer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh I'm stupid - I was tagged you instead of  MichaelCoker :| sorry

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry I definitely do not mean you suggested anything, you just worded what I was unclear about much better than me.

Comment: @MichaelCoker That's totally fine. Thank you

Comment: Thanks all, lessons learned today. And I'm very sorry @Dippas, I didn't mean to disrespect or cause such an issue, but my ignorance is no excuse and I'm sorry for that. I appreciate this community and value our rapport immensely and I'm sorry for any problems and frustration I've caused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So what to do when a user with a gold badge reopened an closed duplicated question just to answer it?

That depends.  If *they know that it's a duplicate* and choose to reopen it anyway, only to repeat what's already being said in the duplicate, then that's abusive behavior.  They're knowingly voting to reopen a question that doesn't merit reopening.

If they simply disagree with you that it's a duplicate then it's perfectly acceptable to answer a question you feel merits reopening after having voted to reopen it.  If they're doing this, you should also expect to see information in the answer not already found in the duplicate, to support their position that the questions have meaningful differences relevant to the answer.

You are of course quite right that, "one other person also voted to reopen" doesn't mean the questions aren't duplicates.  Of course, the burden is on *you* to show that the user clearly understands that the questions are duplicates, and that they voted to reopen a question they fully realized was already answered by the duplicate, not on *them* to show that they didn't, so if you're going to be flagging stuff like this you'll want to focus on explaining to the mod how the duplicate already answered the question adequately, or how the information they've posted in their answer(s) is already covered in the duplicate, rather than purely that the user voted to reopen and then answered (which is in itself not problematic behavior).  Keep in mind when doing this that the mod likely won't be an expert in the subject matter.

As to the specifics of your first example, the user has since commented saying that they just don't *like* closing questions, and they've posted an answer that's suggesting the same solution as an answer in the duplicate, so this is a very clear case of someone reopening a clear duplicate just to duplicate the answer.  Note that *that* is the kind of information you need to include in your flag message if you want a mod to be able to act on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I marked both questions as duplicates of the same question
>   [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Just addressing this choice for the [2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685109/why-does-my-grid-have-a-lot-of-whitespace-between-each-line):
While both questions make a similar observation - a spacing between `inline-block` elements - both warrant (and have!) different (accepted) answers. The useful answers to the linked question are not useful answers to the 2nd question and as such, we should probably find a better, more similar duplicate (or reopen in case none can be found).

Just for reference...

- [The linked 'canonical' question asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements): How to get rid of a *horizontal* space between `<span>`s? (Answer: hide white-space)
- [The 2nd 'duplicate' question asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685109/why-does-my-grid-have-a-lot-of-whitespace-between-each-line): Why is there a *vertical* gap between 10x10 `<div>`s but not between 20x20 `<div>`s? (Answer: default line-height is 19px)

IMHO the 'canonical' answers [do not fully address the 2nd question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) (no mention of `line-height` at all).

Comment: `The useful answers to the linked question are not useful answers to the 2nd question` What's your basis for this assertion?  The questions are the same, they have the same problem.  That there are multiple solutions to that problem (as evidenced by the many different solutions presented in the canonical) doesn't mean the questions aren't duplicates.  And in fact the accepted answer's solution *is* seen in one of the answers in the canonical.  I don't see any evidence at all that there's any relevant differences here.

Comment: @Servy My basis for this assertion is looking at the most upvoted answers to the linked question - basically "use <li>", use "white-space-collapsing", "use font-size: 0", "add comments", "use font-face" and "use word-spacing" - and realizing that all those aren't answers or are bad answers to the 2nd question. There is a link-only answer pointing to "Flex" at the linked question, granted. But how should the asker of the 2nd question know that his answer is hidden there and not in the other, more upvoted answers?

Comment: @le_m Since I was witnessed to the whole thing (I was commenting on that same question), I saw MichaelCoker suggestion a solution in a comment that was approved by the OP, that also asked him to write it as answer - Then MichaelCoker replied something like "nope. it's a duplicate", so it is duplicate after all. There is no question that there can be more than one solution, but as the OP **confirmed** that is solved their problem, then this closed as duplicate  correctly

Comment: @AlonEitan Sorry, I disagree. Questions are kept on SO for future reference. If I were to have the same question as *literally stated by OP* and then follow through to the canonical, I wouldn't find any answer. Keeping this question linked to that canonical as it is is not useful for  anyone. If OP would edit the question to fit his/her intend (which I cannot know), then perhaps, yes.

Comment: _Questions are kept on SO for future reference_ - That's a different case, as @Servy wote [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348548/gold-badger-reopening-a-duplicated-question-to-answer/348557#comment469337_348548), we want to close those bucase when you're looking for an answer. it's up to you to know what you're looking for - I rarely ask on SO, **not** because I know everything,  but because I know what I'm looking for - And Google always know to give me what I need, and it's almost always an old question from SO (That's why I agree that may steatment on that question was false

Comment: @AlonEitan Still don't think it's a valid duplicate unless the question is reworded. But I agree with you that in many such cases, knowing *what* to look for is already a big help and most often than not sufficient in helping OP find the solution by himself.