# Are there times when a duplicate should not be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm asking based on my experience [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923474/storing-and-querying-entity-lineage).

The question was closed as a duplicate by a gold badge holder shortly after a member answered it.  The member who answered the question then re-opened it, and when the gold badge holder asked why, the member who answered the question said the question was not an exact duplicate.

But rather than finding one of many exact duplicates, that member went on to explain how they chose not to re-close it as a duplicate for several reasons

1. Sometimes people need a little kickstart.
2. The asker is an active contributor (not a leech).
3. Virtually all of the asker's other questions were well received.
4. The asker is always resptcful and grateful.
5. We all have dupes in one fashion or another.

Which leads me to my question:  Should I not mark a duplicate as a duplicate under certain circumstances?

Comment: if it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate. (pretty sure this is a duplicate too... the offending user even made a similar comment.)

Comment: here it is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348548/gold-badger-reopening-a-duplicated-question-to-answer

Comment: Curious that you failed to mention that when it was closed as a duplicate, it was pointed to an inappropriate answer.  Had that not been the case, I would have left it as.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti : "The member who answered the question then re-opened it, and when the gold badge holder asked why, the member who answered the question said the question was not an exact duplicate."

Comment: Exact was never a consideration.  It was wrong.  OP needed a bottom up while the link was a top down.  I have closed questions, but I was sure to link it an appropriate answer.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - oh dear lord.  I was summarizing, not quoting you word by word.  I'm sorry if you feel that's a misrepresentation and completely skews my recap of the scenario.

Comment: P.S.  My question isn't about reasons for re-opening a duplicate.  It's about reasons why one would not mark a duplicate as a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But rather than finding one of many exact duplicates, that member went on to explain how they chose not to re-close it as a duplicate for several reasons
>
> 1. Sometimes people need a little kickstart.
> 2. The asker is an active contributor (not a leech).
> 3. Virtually all of the asker's other questions were well received.
> 4. The asker is always resptcful and grateful.
> 5. We all have dupes in one fashion or another.

All of these reasons are irrelevant. We don't close questions because of the past behaviour of the asker, but rather because of what is written in the question. Furthermore, in general closing as a duplicate should not be seen as reproaching the asker -- in fact, non-obvious duplicates can be genuinely useful by consolidating answers while providing alternative search terms for issues. Finally, if the close voter feels it would be helpful to clarify how the answer to the dupe target applies to the concrete issue raised by the asker, they can do so through a brief comment -- there is no need to answer, or to leave the question open.